# Render internal wall after doorway brickup

Tags: concrete, walls, render

As per the picture, I have a room with a bricked up wall.

All the walls are concrete. The doorway has been bricked and covered with what I believe to be cement.

So far I have sanded the doorway with an electric sander, but still the texture differs quite a bit from the surrounding wall. Not sure any amount of primer and top coats will hide the seam completely.

When I lived in Denmark I remember this amazing product making rough or different textured walls perfectly smooth; A thin and very fine sheet made from fiberglass. I comes pre-primed in rolls and is attached to the wall with wallpaper paste and you apply paint directly to it. Perfect result every time. However I have no idea what the English name would be. Here's the link to a Danish product:

http://www.dyrup.dk/produkter/vaev-filt-og-tapet/dyrup-glasfilt-fin-grundet

I live in Australia now. Any idea what the equivalent name for this product would be in Australia?

Also any tips on rendering this wall?

[image]

Comment: http://www.roosintl.com/portfolio-item/texturglas/.   Search under fiberglass wall covering